# Dice roll game some advice

Tags: python

This is my first project writen with python, im looking for some advices to improve my code. Everything works fine, but maybe someone has some ideas how to make my code more efective or to try it out in some other way?
Thanks

**Her's my code:**

```
        print("Welcome to dice roll!")
        game_on = ""

        while game_on != "YES" and game_on != "NO":
            game_on = input("Would you like to start the game? Type Yes or No: ")
            if game_on.upper() != "YES" and game_on.upper() != "NO":
                print("You must type Yes or NO")
            elif game_on.upper() == "YES":
                print(dice_roll())
                play_again = input("Would you like to play again? Type Yes or No: ")
                if play_again.upper() == "YES":
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            else:
                break
```

**For the rolling i use:**

```
           import random

           def dice_roll():
                return random.randint(1,6)
```

Comment: If you want a code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!